# Syntax error when running a script with python 2

Tags: python

I'm  a newbie in python.

I try to run Alexa with my ReSpeaker Mic and I'm following all the steps from https://github.com/respeaker/avs. But I have a bunch of errors when I try to run `alexa-auth`.

The issues are the following :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/lilitsve/.local/bin/alexa-auth", line 7, in <module>
    from avs.auth import main
  File "/home/lilitsve/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/avs/auth.py", line 9, in <module>
    import tornado.httpserver
  File "/home/lilitsve/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/httpserver.py", line 144
    def __init__(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I found some similar issues which suggested to use python3 instead of python2. On my computer (Linux Ubuntu), I have python2.7, python3 and python3.7 installed, but I don't know how to switch to python3 and make my code use the python3 version. But still, **I'm not sure my problem is coming from the python version** (need confirmation)

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: related/dupe: [How do I tell a Python script to use a particular version](//stackoverflow.com/q/11170827)

Comment: When executing the code, use `python3 file.py`  instead of `python`

Comment: Thank you @Aran-Fey. Thank you @Peter Wood. As mentionned in the related issue, I tried to add the version 
 at the first line of the script `#!/usr/bin/python3` instead of `#!/usr/bin/python`. That resolved my issue but now I'm getting `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lilitsve/.local/bin/alexa-auth", line 7, in <module>
    from avs.auth import main
ImportError: No module named 'avs'` The module avs is installed with `pip install avs` but it seems not to be recognized by the python3. Now, how can I specify the dependencies to be used under/with the python3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways to use any version and run your project in your desire version.

**Step 1:**

If you are using Ubuntu. run this command in your command line

`pip3 install virtualenv`

**Step 2 :** 
Enter your avs project folder

`cd avs`

Then run this

`virtualenv -p python3 venv`   [python3 = python version; venv=virtualenv name]

`source venv/bin/activate`

**Finally**

`python setup.py install`

above the example your project will run on python3

**Another way that is on your gitrepo example**
`https://github.com/respeaker/avs`

```
sudo apt-get install mpg123 mpv
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly \
gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 python3-gi python3-gst-1.0
sudo apt-get install python3-pyaudio
```

I change python-pyaudio to python3-pyaudio

If have more queries comment below

Comment: Thank you ! But now I'm getting `usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied`

Comment: Unfortunately, the second example (modifying the gitrepo example) is not working for me, I still get the same errors.

Comment: does first example work or show same errors? If first example .. first have to activate venv and then run the command .

Comment: the first example is giving the following error `usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...] or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...] or: setup.py --help-commands or: setup.py cmd --help error: no commands supplied` I suppose `python setup.py` needs arguments, but I don't know which ones.

Comment: ```python setup.py install```   This will work.. I test it on my local pc. works perfectly

Comment: I tried `python setup.py install`, the packages were installed, but when I try to run the `alexa-auth` I'm getting the same errors as those mentionned in my post